# C# Windows Forms LiveCharts GeoMap

Tags: c#, winforms, livecharts

simply this works:

```
                LiveCharts.WinForms.GeoMap geoMap = new LiveCharts.WinForms.GeoMap();
                Dictionary<string, double> keyValues = new Dictionary<string, double>();
                keyValues["China"] = 81285;
                keyValues["United States"] = 75066;
                keyValues["Italia"] = 74384;
                keyValues["ES"] = 56196;
                keyValues["Ireland"] = 29046;
                keyValues["France"] = 25233;
                keyValues["UK"] = 9849;
                keyValues["CA"] = 3579;
                keyValues["PK"] = 1179;
                keyValues["IN"] = 719;
                geoMap.HeatMap = keyValues;
                geoMap.Source = $"{Application.StartupPath}\\World.xml";
                metroTabPage2.Controls.Add(geoMap);
                geoMap.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
```

And this doesn't

```
                LiveCharts.WinForms.GeoMap geoMap = new LiveCharts.WinForms.GeoMap();
                Dictionary<string, double> keyValues = new Dictionary<string, double>();
                int randomnumber = 0;
                for (int i=0;i<_drzave.Count();i++)
                {
                    randomnumber = randomnumber + 551;
                    keyValues[$"{_drzave[i].sImeDrzave}"] = randomnumber;
                }
                geoMap.HeatMap = keyValues;
                geoMap.Source = $"{Application.StartupPath}\\World.xml";
                metroTabPage2.Controls.Add(geoMap);
                geoMap.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
```

In list `_drzave` I contain list of countries that have names and tags of countries.
This wont work when using for loop, but it works when I set the values manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```cs
{
    var geoMap = new LiveCharts.WinForms.GeoMap();
    var heatMap = new Dictionary<string, double>();

    var randomnumber = 0;

    foreach(var item in _drzave)
    {
        randomnumber += 551;
        heatMap.TryAdd(item.sImeDrzave, randomnumber);
    }

    geoMap.HeatMap = heatMap;
    geoMap.Source = $"{Application.StartupPath}\\World.xml";
    metroTabPage2.Controls.Add(geoMap);
    geoMap.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
}
```

Comment: Visual Studio says TryAdd doesn't exist.

Comment: Just tried using Add instead of TryAdd (Debugger launches but map is still blank)

Comment: So your source _drzave is empty or wrong. It perfectly works for me . And yes, I've forgot. TryAdd works for .NET Core 3+

Comment: For some reason list was adding empty characters in database, etc. "US    " instead of "US". Thank you for help :)

Comment: Not at all, just try to find out more coding styles, because as I could show the code can be mush easier and readable. Good luck.